# REST with Polymorphic DataContracts - Deserialization Fails

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, datacontract

This has been driving me nuts all day, as I've made no changes yet I swear this was working the way I had intended yesterday.

I have a WCF 4 REST service defined with the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPhoneFeaturesManagementHost
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/accounts/{accountNumber}/phoneNumbers/{phoneNumber}/features/{featureType}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void UpdateFeatureStatus(string accountNumber, string phoneNumber, string featureType, FeatureUpdateRequest updateRequest);
}
```

I also have the following types defined:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(One900FeatureUpdateRequest))]
public abstract class FeatureUpdateRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public FeatureStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Status: {0}, Effective Date: {1}", Status, EffectiveDate);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class One900FeatureUpdateRequest : FeatureUpdateRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool PerformSwitchUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Yesterday I swear I was able to submit POST data of this form:

```
<One900FeatureUpdateRequest>
  <EffectiveDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</EffectiveDate>
  <Status>Enabled</Status>
  <PerformSwitchUpdate>true</PerformSwitchUpdate>
</One900FeatureUpdateRequest>
```

Today that same batch of XML is causing HTTP 400 errors with the following message:

```
Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'One900FeatureUpdateRequest' and root namespace '' (for operation 'UpdateFeatureStatus' and contract ('IPhoneFeaturesManagementHost',  'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.
```

The only XML that seems to work today is the below, and I really really dislike the necessity of adding a namespace plus attribute to describe the subtype of my child DataContract.

```
<FeatureUpdateRequest i:type="One900FeatureUpdateRequest" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.Services.Host">
  <EffectiveDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</EffectiveDate>
  <Status>Enabled</Status>
  <PerformSwitchUpdate>true</PerformSwitchUpdate>
</FeatureUpdateRequest>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might have touched or what I might need to change in order to get back to the prior simple XML format for deserialization?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried this and it unfortunately made no difference.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with the DataContractSerializer, so I instead switched to the old XmlSerializer so I can have direct control over the XML format.  This seemed to work.